# color.cpp:11147: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

My project is about image classification (Multiclass).
When I run the code I faced some problem like this:

> OpenCV(3.4.1) C:\Miniconda3\conda-bld\opencv-suite_1533128839831\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:11147: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor "

Basically I was trying predict my CNN model with a completely new photo to check the result is working or not.
But I failed to check it because of this error.
Can any one help me to solve the error on my code with explanation?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
test_image = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\Shahinur Shakib\Downloads\spyder2\Datasets\test_set\Dog\elephant.jpg')

test_image=cv2.cvtColor(test_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
test_image=cv2.resize(test_image,(200,200))
test_image = np.array(test_image)
test_image = test_image.astype('float32')
test_image /= 255
print (test_image.shape)

if img_channels==1:
    if K.image_dim_ordering()=='th':
        test_image= np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)
        test_image= np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)
        print (test_image.shape)
    else:
        test_image= np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=3) 
        test_image= np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)
        print (test_image.shape)
else:
    if K.image_dim_ordering()=='th':
        test_image=np.rollaxis(test_image,2,0)
        test_image= np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)
        print (test_image.shape)
    else:
        test_image= np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)
        print (test_image.shape)

print((model.predict(test_image)))
print(model.predict_classes(test_image))
result=model.predict_classes(test_image)
if(result==0):
    print("Cat")
elif(result==1):
    print("Dog")
elif(result==2):
    print("Elephant")
elif(result==3):
    print("Hen")
elif(result==4):
    print("Horse")
```

Comment: Does the image path exist? Please check if `test_image` is valid. This kind of error looks like an invalid image.

Comment: The error is telling you that the image you are trying to convert does not have 3 or 4 channels. Most of the time, it is because it is None, since it was not able to load the image. Check the file path and make sure the image is readable.

Comment: Thanks. @kampi  
finally found the solution. you guys are absolutely right about the solution. problem was in "elephant.jpg" And solution is  "elephant.png". I made a mistake with the file format.

Comment: Thanks. @api55 for the explanation & it helps a lot.

Comment: Can you guys tell me ?
why I am getting this warning Now?

" __main__:22: DeprecationWarning: Both axis > a.ndim and axis < -a.ndim - 1 are deprecated and will raise an AxisError in the future. "

After running the Code my Result is like : 

(200, 200)
(1, 200, 200, 1)
[[3.1009635e-32 1.5325414e-19 1.0000000e+00 3.6132556e-18 1.0779073e-08]]
__main__:22: DeprecationWarning: Both axis > a.ndim and axis < -a.ndim - 1 are deprecated and will raise an AxisError in the future.
[2]
Elephant